# date computation give a detailed calendar

Tags: date, datetime

given a detailed calendar,

```
Sunday
  hrs_per_day 0
Monday
  07:00:00 11:59:00 5 hours
  13:00:00 15:59:00 3 hours
  hrs_per_day 8
Tuesday
  07:00:00 11:59:00 5 hours
  13:00:00 15:59:00 3 hours
  hrs_per_day 8
Wednesday
  07:00:00 11:59:00 5 hours
  13:00:00 15:59:00 3 hours
  hrs_per_day 8
Thursday
  07:00:00 11:59:00 5 hours
  13:00:00 15:59:00 3 hours
  hrs_per_day 8
Friday
  07:00:00 12:59:00 6 hours
  hrs_per_day 6
Saturday
  hrs_per_day 0
hrs_per_week 38
```

how can i compute start and end dates of a task based on its duration?

suppose i have a task that can start **after** Sunday 8 AM, and it will take 23 (8+8+7) hours of work.
then the start date should be Monday 07:00:00, and the end date should be Wednesday 15:00:00.

I can try to find out the dates manually, but not sure how to implement it in a program

```js
function get_start_end_dates(can_start_after, duration_hrs, calendar_data){
   //  ??????????
   return {start_date, end_date}
}
```

Comment: Run a loop that per date subtracts `hrs_per_day` from the task duration. When reaching zero or negative for the remaining hours, you've found the last date of the task. If zero, the hour is the end of the day; if negative, calculate the hour of the date.

Comment: @Gustav  I don't think it is as trivial as you describe it. can you show some code with tested examples?

Comment: It is. At least, it is the simplest method I can think of. However, have in mind, please, that SO is not a code writing service, but a code helping forum.